# Merging overlapping buildings but not adjacent buildings using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, merge

I have a dataset that has buildings generated from satellites which leads to imperfect building outlines. The buildings circled in red are one building but the computer drew them as having multiple pieces. 
[image]

How can I merge them into one building while keeping the other buildings that are adjacent but not overlapping from merging. I tried every union, merge, dissolve, and nothing was able to distinguish between overlapping and adjacent. Or I wasn't able to make it distinguish between the two. I am using ArcMap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Intersect the buildings with themselves
2. Select By Location to only select buildings with overlaps:
   [image]
3. Dissolve the selected features
4. Start editing on building and delete all selected features. Stop editing
5. Append the dissolved features back to the buildings.